# Why annual granularity of annotation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I import a simple data frame from Excel. Seven dates, 12/2021 - 12/2027, each date a year apart, each associated with a number. I want to add an annotation (a vertical line separating the actual historical value from forecasted numbers), and text making this clear.

```
df.plot()

#annotation
plt.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2023-6-01'))
plt.text(pd.to_datetime('2022-06-01'), 20**6, 'actual')
plt.text(pd.to_datetime('2023-06-01'), 20**6, 'forecast')

plt.show()
```

The system rounds my placements to the nearest year-end. So with the code above, all three placements are set six months earlier than I want them to be.

[image: frustrating graph]

How can I get the line and text to appear in the specified months?

Comment: How did you declare your X axis?  It looks like the data are all only on year boundaries.

Comment: Yes, the data is on year boundaries. Does matplotlib allow placement of annotations only on dates where there's also data? It seems like an odd limitation.

Comment: For `axvline` it does.  You're annotating the graph data, and the graph data exists only at whole years.  There are ways to draw lines without relying on the axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by using a subplots. So replace the code above with

```
figure, ax = plt.subplots() # need both of those; subplots is a tuple
ax.plot(df) 

#annotation
ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2022-6-01'))
ax.text(pd.to_datetime('2021-06-01'), 20**6, 'actual')
ax.text(pd.to_datetime('2022-06-01'), 20**6, 'forecast')

plt.show()
```

and the annotations can be placed freely.